# Does "loadHTMLfile" or "load" sends the requested url of page?

Tags: php, dom

I would like to know if by using does the loaded page gets the address or anything related of the request-to-load site ? If so, what is the method of hiding or changing that ?

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
$dom->load('www.domain.com');
libxml_clear_errors();
$xPath = new DOMXPath($dom);
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>The DOM will not have the URL *added* to it as a special property.  So it would only be there if it's actually in the document (header, footer, meta tag, etc.).</s>

EDIT: `$dom` *does* actually have a [`documentURI`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.documenturi) property containing the URL.

However, none of the calls output anything at all, which I think it what you man by a clean call.  So the client won't see `documentURI` unless you explicitly echo it somewhere.

Comment: @Rocky, I don't know what you mean.

Comment: I mean If i load your website with this script and get some data, will you be able to see that I did it ?

Comment: @Rocky, no, unless you explicitly output `documentURI` or a variable containing the URL.  You can verify this yourself using a tool like Firebug.